# What's substantive difference between function and Object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

When I learn js at first I get a voice which say everything is an object, so I think maybe function is an object and object is an object too.

But when I learn prototype, some thing different to my thought.

```
function helloworld(){                                                                       
    this.hi = 'world';
}
var foo = { 
    'sth':'happend'
};


function bar(){};

bar.prototype = foo;
console.log(new bar().sth);

bar.prototype = helloworld;
console.log(new bar().hi);
```

And I get print

```
happend
undefined
```

Then I replace `bar.prototype = helloworld;` to `bar.prototype = new helloworld();`  I get correct result.

```
happend
world
```

I'm a newbie, maybe it's a stupid question, but I really want to know what's wrong in my mind?  is function not an Object?  could anybody help me?  thanks a lot..

Comment: **this.hi**  is a property of helloworld, not the bar, so **bar.hi** will definitely print undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a function is an object, and can have properties as well:

```
var foo = {};
var bar = function(x){return x+1};
foo.prop = "hello ";
bar.prop = "world!"; // works the same!
alert(foo.prop + bar.prop);
```

> What's substantive difference between function and Object?

Well, a function is an object that can be called - "normal" objects can't:

```
bar(4); // 5
foo(4); // Error: 'foo' is not a function
```

> I replace `bar.prototype = helloworld;` with `bar.prototype = new helloworld();` to get correct result
>
> I really want to know what's wrong in my mind?

You must not confuse constructor functions for instances that were created by calling them. `helloworld` is an object (just as `bar` is in the example above), but it's a very different object than `new helloworld()` (which inherits from `helloworld.prototype`, and was initialised by the constructor with a `hi` property).